# Can you move an App Service Plan in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-resource-group

I know that you can move and App Service or Webapp but can you move an App Service Plan from one resource group to another? If you can then I'm running into the following issue. I've created a basic App Service Plan under resource group A and I would like to move it to a newly created resource group B. When I attempt this I get an error that states the resource group cannot be found. I'm moving the App Service Plan + Webapp but still get the same error. Resource groups A & B are located in the same region and under the same subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Since App Service Plan is not listed  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources) its safe to assume that you cannot move it. It does leave me wondering why your allowed to select your plan and try to move it. I'm not sure why I have the option to move a resource that can't be moved but hopefully someone else can explain.